# Putty auto-accept "Connect Once"?

Tags: ssh, putty

When I first run **Putty**, a window with the button `Connect once` appears, which means that it does not save **cache data**.

How can I make it run **by default** without having to click `Connect once` every time?

I have tried to find some command line arguments to run it from a shortcut, but I couldn't find any related information.

Answer (score 1):

To be clear, you are runnning putty *on* Unix, rather than using the normal method of `ssh`=OpenSSH in a terminal? Anyway...

Not directly; you could run (commandline) `plink` and parse its (stderr) output to get the fingerprint of the 'unknown' hostkey -- or `ssh-keyscan` to get the actual hostkey blob (FYI also works on Win10 up which now has a port of OpenSSH) -- and pass to `-hostkey` to cause putty to accept that key on one connection. To use multiple times (but not always, as the cache would) you could enter into a profile and `-load` that profile.

Comment: No, I am running putty on windows and I want to run it in every time in "Connect once" mode, without clicking a button. I want to "automate it" without change a source files and etc. In anyway it a strange what this app not have additional argument for this.

Comment: I got it ! thanks !